# How to make "value is in dateframe column" quicker

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, runtime, iteration

I have code which has `userID`, `categoryID` and `date` as input values. I want to check if the entries are valid, e.g. if the `userID` does even exist in my dataset. 
It works the way I do it, but I have to wait a few seconds(!) until the main programm is executed.

```
var_uid = int(input("Please enter a user ID: "))
var_catid = input("Please enter a category ID: ")
var_date = input("Please enter a date to restrict the considered data (YYYY-MM-DD): ")


if (~var_uid in df_data['UserID'].values) :
    print("There is no such user with this UserID. Please enter a different UserID.")
elif (~df_data['CategoryID'].str.contains(var_catid).any()) :
    print("There is no such category with this CategoryID. Please enter a different CategoryID")
else:
    ### I convert my date to datetime object to be able to do some operations with it. ###
date = pd.to_datetime(var_date)

s_all = df_data[df_data.columns[7]]
s_all_datetime = pd.to_datetime(s_all)
df_data['UTCtime'] = s_all_datetime

min_date_str = "2012-04-03"
min_date = pd.to_datetime(min_date_str)
max_date_str = "2013-02-16"
max_date = pd.to_datetime(max_date_str)


if (date < min_date or date > max_date) :
    print("There is noch such date. Please enter a different date from 2012-04-03 until 2013-02-16")
else:
    some code
```

I know, stackoverflow is not for doing the work and in fact my code works. Still, could you at least give some hints what would be faster implementations? The dataframe has 230k lines and it's of course not the best way if my program has to run over it with every if clause.

I thought I could extract e.g. the unique values of my `UserID` column,save it in a list and check it with my if clause.
But

```
df_data['UserID'].unique.tolist()
```

doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

/EDIT: Here's `df_data.info()` and `df_data.head()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 227428 entries, 0 to 227427
Data columns (total 8 columns):
UserID            227428 non-null int64
VenueID           227428 non-null object
CategoryID        227428 non-null object
CategoryName      227428 non-null object
Latitude          227428 non-null float64
Longitude         227428 non-null float64
TimezoneOffset    227428 non-null int64
UTCtime           227428 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2), object(4)
memory usage: 13.9+ MB
None
```

Head:

```
   UserID                   VenueID                CategoryID         CategoryName   Latitude  Longitude  TimezoneOffset                         UTCtime
0     470  49bbd6c0f964a520f4531fe3  4bf58dd8d48988d127951735  Arts & Crafts Store  40.719810 -74.002581            -240  Tue Apr 03 18:00:09 +0000 2012
1     979  4a43c0aef964a520c6a61fe3  4bf58dd8d48988d1df941735               Bridge  40.606800 -74.044170            -240  Tue Apr 03 18:00:25 +0000 2012
2      69  4c5cc7b485a1e21e00d35711  4bf58dd8d48988d103941735       Home (private)  40.716162 -73.883070            -240  Tue Apr 03 18:02:24 +0000 2012
3     395  4bc7086715a7ef3bef9878da  4bf58dd8d48988d104941735       Medical Center  40.745164 -73.982519            -240  Tue Apr 03 18:02:41 +0000 2012
4      87  4cf2c5321d18a143951b5cec  4bf58dd8d48988d1cb941735           Food Truck  40.740104 -73.989658            -240  Tue Apr 03 18:03:00 +0000 2012
```

Comment: Could you maybe post `df_data.info()` and `df.head()` to see the example of source data?

Comment: you can simply check it this way `df_data[(df_data['UserID'] == var_uid) & (df_data['CategoryID'] == var_catid)]`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if I write ``if (df_data[(df_data['UserID'] != var_uid)]):`` I get an error because of ambiguous truth values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating lookup indexes, then you get log-speed access. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = int(1e6)
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'uid': np.arange(n), 
    'catid': np.repeat('foo bar baz', n),
})
```

The slower version:

```
>>> %timeit for i in range(n // 2, n // 2 + 1000): i in df.uid.values
1 loop, best of 3: 2.32 s per loop
```

However you can pre-compute the index:

```
>>> uids = pd.Index(df.uid.values)
>>> %timeit for i in range(n // 2, n//2 + 1000): i in uids
1000 loops, best of 3: 412 µs per loop
```

Whoah, that's fast. Let's see how long it takes to create the index:

```
>>> %timeit uids = pd.Index(df.uid.values)
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.5 µs per loop
```

You could also use `set` (although for ints like `UserID` its faster to use pandas Index), e.g. for `CategoryID` you could precompute:

```
>>> catids = set(s for catid in df.catid.values for s in catid.split())
```

and then check

```
>>> catid in catids
```

which is going to be a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is the most complete one.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by

> But df_data['UserID'].unique.tolist() doesn't work.

?

Do you mean the command is failing?  That's probably because unique is a function, you have to call it

```
df_data['UserID'].unique().tolist()
```

Or do you mean its still too slow?  In that case, you probably don't want to use a python list, since its still going to have to go over every entry.  If you instead use a set, you will have worst case O(logn) retrieval time.  So

```
set(df['UserID'].tolist())
```

Now that makes looking up the user quicker, but if the categories need something more complex called on them (like str.contains), you will still need to go over the list.  But if categories have a much smaller cardinality, you could probably just apply unique to it and deal with the smaller list.

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of containment checks you should make User (and Category) an index:

```
if (~var_uid in df_data['UserID'].values) :

elif (~df_data['CategoryID'].str.contains(var_catid).any()) :
```

once these are in the index (Note: this should be done outside of this block, not every time):

```
df = df_data.set_index(["UserId", "CategoryID"])
```

then you can look up in O(1):

```
user_id in df.index.levels[0]
category_id in df.index.levels[1]  # granted this doesn't do the str contains (but that'll always be inefficient)
```

---

You can create these manually, again you have to have to do these *once* rather than for every lookup to get the benefit:

```
pd.Index(df_date["UserID"])
# if lots of non-unique users this will be more space efficient
pd.Index(df_date["UserID"].unique())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to all contributors! For my `UserID` I used the solution with setting it as the index. For my `CategoryID` I created the set and stored it in my programm.

Plus, I found another bottleneck which was even worse:

```
s_all = df_data[df_data.columns[7]]
s_all_datetime = pd.to_datetime(s_all)
df_data['UTCtime'] = s_all_datetime
```

It converts my `'UTCtime'` column to datetime objects ... 230k iterations with it ... ^^
I just did it once and stored the new dataframe now. Just has to load the .csv every time, but that's much faster.